# VRRP Election ? Why Skew required

Tags: switching

I`m having a query regarding VVRP,If there are multiple backups then as per the election Skew time is useful.But assume there is a tie in priority then as per my research i am seeing which is having the highest IP address will be the master.So kindly help me out in detail.Why skew matters if highest ip elects as the next master ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is when there are several competing devices, you want to reduce the churn.

This [link](https://lkhill.com/vrrp-skew-time-and-always-be-learning/) can be give you more details:

Comment: Thanks for that its clear now..and I the one who posted that query too in the same portal. And one last thing can you clarify ...in vrrp only master will send hello packets right ???

Comment: By default, the master router sends VRRP advertisement packets every second to all members of the VRRP group. These packets indicate that the master router is still operational. If the master router fails or becomes unreachable, the backup router with the highest priority value becomes the new master router.

Comment: @Harsha D  please flag solved/answered